# sphinx autocomplete CALL SNIPPETS excerpts not returning result set

Tags: sphinx

i am able to get a result set from print_r($stmt->fetchAll()); however, i cannot get a result set from print_r($r); below is the exact code from https://github.com/adriannuta/SphinxAutocompleteExample. the only change is the sql_query inside the sphinx.conf file.

ajax_suggest_excerpts.php

```
require_once 'common.php';
require_once 'functions.php';
$indexes = 'simplecomplete';
$arr =array();
$q = trim($_GET['term']);
$stmt = $ln_sph->prepare("SELECT * FROM $indexes WHERE MATCH(:match) LIMIT 0,10 OPTION ranker=sph04");


$aq = explode(' ',$q);
if(strlen($aq[count($aq)-1])<3){
$query = $q;
}else{
$query = $q.'*';
}
$stmt->bindValue(':match', $query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$docs = array();
$title = "";    
$stmsnp = $ln_sph->prepare("CALL SNIPPETS(:doc,'simplecomplete',:query)");
$stmsnp->bindValue(':query',$query,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmsnp->bindParam(':doc',$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);

print_r($stmt->fetchAll()); //THIS RETURNS RESULT SET

foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $r){
    $title = $r['city'];
    $stmsnp->execute();
    $r = $stmsnp->fetch();  
    print_r($r); //THIS DOES NOT. 
    $arr[] = array('id' => utf8_encode($r['city']),'label' =>utf8_encode( $r['city']));
}

echo json_encode($arr);
exit();
```

sphinx.conf

```
source simplecomplete
{
    type                = mysql
    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = swflorib
    sql_pass        = cii65419
    sql_db          = swflorib_db
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306 

    sql_query           = SELECT id, Sic_Code_description, Sic_Code6_Description, City, hidden_keywords FROM no_admin_emails GROUP BY Company_Name
    sql_field_string    = Sic_Code_description  
    sql_field_string    = Sic_Code6_Description
    sql_field_string    = City
    sql_field_string    = hidden_keywords
}

index simplecomplete
{
    source              = simplecomplete
    path                = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/simplecomplete
    docinfo             = extern
    charset_type        = utf-8
    min_word_len        = 3
    enable_star         = 1
    min_prefix_len      = 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of fetchAll
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

> returns an array containing all of the remaining rows in the result set.

So the fetchAll inside the print_r() fetches all the rows from the database. The fetchAll inside the foreach() then has no rows left to fetch!

Looks like a misunderstanding of PHP/pdo.